Validator function in Python NDN
I've been working on getting a standard NDN process working, and I cannot figure the validator function out for the life of me, and getting a proper function call for it.
This function is required to express an interest in a data packet, and what I have for it so far is:
formal = Name.from_str("ndntest/examples") sign = ndn_format_0.3.SignaturePtrs() vdator = Validator(formal, sign, "")
but I'm getting the error: TypeError: Callable() takes no arguments when I run this. I'm at a loss since the documentation is very poor.
The formal variable is written properly, but since the sign one takes 3 optional variables and 2 dynamically-generated ones I wasn't sure how to write the function call for it. I believe it works.
